# Why Qt+QML application deployment needs some extra libraries

Tags: qt, qml

When you want to deploy your **Qt + QML** application you need to put **QtGui4, QtCore4 and QtDeclarative4** libraries besides your project that is reasonable. But they aren't enough and you also need to include **QtNetwork4, QtSql, QtXmlPattern4 and QtScript4** event if you haven't used them in your project. Why are the needed? Are they used in QtDeclarative4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

`QtDeclarative` contains a big bunch of things. The benefit that QML supports many transparent uses of functionalities that needs extra wirings in C++ comes from `QtDeclarative` bundling lots of things for you. Hence the dependencies.

There's no such thing as a perfect life, I guess.